Android Studio 2024.1.2 - Error running 'app' No target device found
I know this question has been asked and answered but none of the responses worked for me with Android Studio 2024.1.2. I'm positing this in the hope that it will help someone else. These steps would have saved me several hours of frustration!

I'm a long time developer but a total beginner with Android. The basic hello world program took me about 5 minutes with my other computer running Android Studio 3.5.2 but it took me all afternoon to get this to work with Android Studio 2024.1.2 as things have changed.
Here are the steps that worked for me to create the basic hello world program that supports adding widgets.

Run Android Studio.
Select Empty Views Activity (NOT Empty Activity!!! - otherwise there will be no layout folder under res!!).
Click Finish (this will take a few minutes).
Run the app. You will see an error message Error running 'app' No target device found.
From the menu - Tools | Device Manager.
Click Add New Device.
Create Virtual Device.
From the Select Hardware form, select the type of emulator you wish to use - for example Phone - Small Phone, then next next finish.

Now when you run the app, it will display in the emulator.

otherwise there will be no layout folder under res!!). - hint: you can create this folder yourself by hand if missing at any time (you might need to switch to Project Files view in file tree first, though)

Cool thanks for that. This is probably trivial for someone who knows what they are doing. My problem is I'm following tutorials that are now out of date. You are saying you can just create the folder and then add widgets? That doesn't work for me. I get an empty folder named layout with nothing in it. What am I missing?

Here's a documentation you probably want to read: Android app resources overview
